# Adding jquery autocomplete to fields added after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery UI Autocomplete to call a link to a DB to populate  a form dropdown.
This is working fine, but I also have a function to add further form fields to the form (with the same name/class) and I want to apply the autocomplete function to these.

Is this possible, and how can I re-call the autocomplete function for the new form fields.

My javascript code is below...

```
var count = 0;

$(function(){

$('input.books').each(function() {
var autoCompelteElement = this;
var formElementName = $(this).attr('name');
var hiddenElementID  = formElementName + '_autocomplete_hidden';
/* change name of orig input */
$(this).attr('name', formElementName + '_autocomplete_label');
/* create new hidden input with name of orig input */
$(this).after("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + formElementName + "\" id=\"" + hiddenElementID + "\" />");
$(this).autocomplete({source:'search.php', minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var selectedObj = ui.item;
        $(autoCompelteElement).val(selectedObj.label);
        $('#'+hiddenElementID).val(selectedObj.value);
        return false;
    }
});
});


$('p#add_field').click(function(){
        count += 1;
            $('#books').append(
            '<tr>'
            + '<td><input type="text" name="BookName_' + count + '" id="BookName" class="books" /> </td>'
            + '<td><input type="text" name="Length_' + count + '" id="Length_' + count + '" /> </td> '
            + '<td><input type="text" name="ISBN_' + count + '" id="ISBN_' + count + '" /> </td> '
            + '<td><input type="text" name="Year_' + count + '" id="Year_' + count + '" /> </td>'
            + '</tr>'
            + '<strong>Link #' + count + '</strong><br />' );
        });



});
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the autocomplete method on those new fields?

```
var newRow = '<tr>'
        + '<td><input type="text" name="BookName_' + count + '" id="BookName" class="books" /> </td>'
        + '<td><input type="text" name="Length_' + count + '" id="Length_' + count + '" /> </td> '
        + '<td><input type="text" name="ISBN_' + count + '" id="ISBN_' + count + '" /> </td> '
        + '<td><input type="text" name="Year_' + count + '" id="Year_' + count + '" /> </td>'
        + '</tr>';
        //+ '<strong>Link #' + count + '</strong><br />';  <--this line can not be added to a table like this! 
$('#books tbody').append(newRow);
newRow.autocomplete( ..options..);
```

You can not append that strong element line to the table like that. The browser is fixing it, but that is very bad practice. Append it after the element if that is where you want it.

Comment: i dont actually need that strong element it is just for testing purposes at the moment (i am following this tutorial: http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/58/adding-unlimited-form-fields-with-jquery-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building your HTML with strings you can use jQuery to build it and attach autocomplete at the same time:

```
$('p#add_field').click(function(){
    count += 1;
    var tr = $(document.createElement('tr'));
    $.forEach(['BookName_', 'Length_', 'ISBN_', 'Year_'], function(key){
        var td = $(document.createElement('td'));
        var input = $(document.createElement('input')).attr('type', 'text')
                                                      .attr('name', key+count)
                                                      .attr('id', key+count)
                                                      .autocomplete(// AUTOCOMPLETE HERE);
        var strong = $(document.createElement('strong')).html('Link #'+count);
        td.append(input, strong, $(document.createElement('br'));
        tr.append(td);
    });
    $('#books').append(tr);
});
```

This way you're using document.createElement wrapped in the jQuery function so you can just chain the rest of the jQuery methods for building those elements, as well as attaching the autocomplete at the same time, then just using append to build up the elements and attach them as you need.

Comment: thanks for the two replies, but how to I add the autocomplete code to either of them, everything I do stops all of the javascript on the page from working..
In fact if I remove the line:
 .autocomplete(// AUTOCOMPLETE HERE);
and add the ; to .attr('id', key+count (so .attr('id', key+count);) 
the javascript on the page still does not work/no fields are added as the #addfield link is not click-able so is there an error or am I missing something

Comment: i'd have to see your html as to find out why the paragraph tag with the id "add_field" is not clickable